# xp:checkbox value differs in read and edit mode

Tags: java, xpages

on my xpage I have placed a checkbox:

```
<xp:checkBox id="cbOther" value="#{customerBean.customer.other}" disabled="#{!customerBean.customer.editable}" checkedValue="1" uncheckedValue="0">
```

In my back-end code I try to set the value for the checkbox based upon the value of another field:

```
 if(doc.hasItem("fldOtherVal")){
                    if(doc.getItemValueString("fldOtherVal").equals("")){
                        System.out.println("no relations");
                        customer.setOther("0");
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("relations");
                        customer.setOther("1");
                        customer.setOtherVal(doc.getItemValueString("fldOtherVal"));    
                    }                           
                }else{
                    customer.setOther("0");
                }
```

This works fine when I open the customer object in my xpage in read mode. but when I set the customer object to edit mode the value in the checkbox is set to the default value of 0.

Can someone explain me what I am doing incorrect?

Comment: "checkbox is set to the default value of 0" - accept both, "" and 0

Comment: Hi Frantisek, I do not really understand what you want to make me clear. Can you specfiy what I should alter?

Comment: Where exactly is your code from second snippet? Seems it executes after the default from input control.

Comment: it runs in the beforepageload event. there the correct value for the checkbox is set. but after I switch to edit mode (customerbean.customer.setEditable(true)) it is set to the default value?

Comment: I think there is a serious flaw with the checkbox. documentation and examples are rare. especially on the java side. Have you tried the checkboxgroup control instead (<xp:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="1"></xp:selectItem>)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see inconsistency with your document/bean. Chceckbox binds to "other" value, but sometimes refers to "otherVal" field/property.

In case your saved doc contains value "0" in "fldOtherVal" field, your code falls to

```
            System.out.println("relations");
            customer.setOther("1");
            customer.setOtherVal(doc.getItemValueString("fldOtherVal"));
```

branch in. In read mode it shows "1", but writes "0" to otherVal again.

That was my comment about:

```
if(doc.getItemValueString("fldOtherVal").equals("")){
```

does not check for "0" value.

### Edit:

Get back to aliased values of checkbox ("0" and "1").

Update your script to this

```
 // no hasItem check needed
 var other = doc.getItemValue("fldOtherVal"); // must not be multivalue
 if ("".equals(other) || "0".equals(other)) {
      System.out.println("no relations");
      customer.setOther("0");
      customer.setOtherVal("0"); // update "otherVal" also
 } else {
      System.out.println("relations");
      customer.setOther("1");
      customer.setOtherVal("1"); // do not copy value, just set to "1"
 }
```

Comment: yes I still do not get it. what type of value is the xp:checkbox suppose to contain? a boolean or a string? I have simplified my code: <xp:checkBox id="cbOther" value="#{customerBean.customer.other}"></xp:checkBox> and my java code: if(doc.hasItem("fldOther")){customer.setOther(doc.getItemValueString("fldOther"));} but still in read mode the checkbox is enabled but in edit mode it is unchecked. a computed text with <xp:text escape="true" value="#{customerBean.customer.other}"></xp:text> displays that in both states the value is "true". why is the checbox unchecked in edit mode?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `disabled` property of your `<xp:checkbox>` and use `readonly` property instead. Actually, leaving the `disabled` property intact and just adding `readonly` property with the same expression should also work.
If it helps, I'll explain this behavior as the update to this answer.